# How to calculate normalized %CPU per process using Prometheus wmi_exporter using wmi_process_cpu_time_total and wmi_cs_logical_processors

Tags: wmi, promql

1. Using the following promql I'm succeeded to get per process %CPU:

   sum by (process, process_id) (rate(wmi_process_cpu_time_total{instance="my_instance", process="my_process"}[5m]))*100/(***amount_of_cores***)

This returns correct vector if amount_of_cores is hardcoded scalar (in my case - 32). Unfortunately I cannot use hardcoded values here because I have many instances with different amount of cores...

2. In the other hand, the following query returns correct amount of cores on the instance:

   wmi_cs_logical_processors{instance="my_instance"}

Unfortunately when I use this query as a divider - it returns nothing. As I understand the issue is that first query has several labels, but second - only one "instance", so direct dividing returns nothing.

What can I do here?

Answer (score 1):

During writing the question I found the answer. So, in case that someone interesting...
To divide one vector to another with different labels you should use ignoring(labels_not_existing_in_divider), group_left and some aggregator on divider (I used sum).

```
    ((sum by (process, process_id) (rate(wmi_process_cpu_time_total{instance=~"$hostname.*"}[5m]))*100))
/
ignoring(process, process_id) group_left sum (wmi_cs_logical_processors{instance=~"$hostname.*"})
```